# Entity Framework model first conflicting table name

Tags: entity-framework, ef-model-first

I have a database with a table named `System`. When I import it as a model first approach I have a conflict with System namespace in .NET framework. Is there any way to workaround it?

Comment: 6.0. As far as I see I need to use .tt file for it.

Comment: What's the 'Custom Tool Namespace' property set to on the model?

Answer (score -1):

I just needed to check _code.Escape(entity) in *.tt files and set correct name for some table.

Comment: This comment was not helpful.